# Validate App check getToken for custom backend

Tags: firebase, firebase-app-check

I am planning to use Firebase App Check to verify that requests made to my backend services (including Firebase) will be from my app only.

I would like to know how can i validate / verify that the App Check `token` sent from the method `FirebaseAppCheck.instance.getToken()` on my backend ?

PS : my backend is in python but i am more asking about the way to verify than the code, but if you provide the code in python as an example it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for [firebasedocs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/custom-resource-backend)

Answer (score 0):

You can only take advantage of that verifyToken api if you're using a Node.js server, otherwise it's not available yet.

You can manually verify the token though:

https://firebase.blog/posts/2021/10/protecting-backends-with-app-check